# My angular strap navbar will not expand

Tags: angular-strap

I am using `angular-strap` to create a navbar.  It collapses down to the hamburger icon just like it should, but when it is collapsed (hamburger icon) it will not expand to click on a link.  Here is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The `navbar` is responsive like expected.  Also, the `directive` is being instantiated, because the breakpoint in the `link` function gets hit.  As explained above when the `navbar` is in it's `hamburger` state, it won't expand to make it able to click on any of the links.  What else do I need to look at to make this work with `angular-strap`?  How do I make the `hamburger` icon expand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the [collapse directive](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##collapses) in ng-strap 2.1.3.

This was added [very recently](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/336#issuecomment-54554355).

An example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" bs-collapse>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" bs-collapse-toggle>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" ng-bind="config.options.page.pageName" ui-sref="root">Doks</a>
        </div>
        <div bs-collapse-target>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item" ng-class="{active: urlParams.category === category}">
                    <a ui-sref="hasCategory({category: category})">{{category}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked, but only once I put "bs-navbar" where you've got "bs-collapse" above and put "bs-collapse" on the div.container-fluid instead.

Comment: Interesting. This worked for me so I'm going to leave it, but hopefully your comment helps someone else out! Keep in mind that your `bs-navbar` needs to contain the `bs-collapse` - that's the only requirement, I think.

Comment: Excellent solution. Only problem; if you collapse menu in a narrow browserwindow and then expand the window, both the menubutton AND the menu is gone.

Comment: To fix this bug, what @hakanostrom mentioned: add `data-start-collapsed="true"` attribute to bs-collapse directive, and put this code in the css: `@media (min-width: 768px) { .navbar .collapse { display: block !important; } }` With this fix, you will have a default collapsed menu in mobile view, and the menu will be always visible in default view.